# Render form in View and attach additional data as json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, django-views

I have a modal where i render a form inside. Before it opens its requesting the content from a View function. Now i want to pass additional attributes that i can handle inside the ajax.success: function.

**Ajax:**

```
function task_form() {
$.ajax({
    url : "/somewhere/" , // the endpoint
    type : "GET", // http method

    // handle a successful response
    success : function(data) {
    if(data.attr == "whatever"){ 
      do this
    }else{
      do that
    }},

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                errorstuff
    }
});
};
```

**View:**

```
def someview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print("shouldnt happen")
else:
    form = SomeForm()
    response_data = {'form': form}

return render(request, 'formToInsert.html', response_data)
```

I tried using JsonResponse() but i´m not sure how to put the html in a dict there and how to use it on the js side.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should do this:

```
def someview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print("shouldnt happen")
else:
    form = SomeForm()
    response_data = {'form': form}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content-type="application/json")
```

although i'm not sure if SomeForm() is serializable vi the 'json' package. otherwise you could likely use the Django 'serialize' package to do the same thing.

Comment: The serialization is basically my problem. What is the best way of doing this? And  how would you "deserialize" the response into html in the ajax.success ? Or is there a super easy way i dont see? :D

Comment: you need to show some code that you have tried. did you try my answer?  in the Javascript you would set the dataType: 'json', and then you should be able to use the returned data like any other json object